# Roadmap for Azure SQL DW Hyperscale and Azure Synapse

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I'm trying to understand the roadmap for Azure SQL <del>DW</del> DB Hyperscale now that Microsoft has branded Azure SQL DW as Synapse.

1. Is Synapse using Hyperscale under the hood?
2. Whats the recommended Azure SQL <del>DW</del> DB to use with Synapse? General Purpose / Hyperscale / Business Critial? Can either one of them be selected ?
3. Will Azure SQL <del>DW</del> DB Hyperscale, still be available, or it will go away ?

Thanks in advance!

** Edited Question after reading answers : edited to change Azure SQL DW Hyperscale to Azure SQL DB Hyperscale **

Comment: Hi Bedant, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. No. Hyperscale is for Azure SQL and Managed Instance.
2. Synapse is built on Azure SQL Data Warehouse. You cannot use any of the options you mentioned for a data warehouse in Synapse.
3. There is no Azure SQL DW Hyperscale, sorry, it never existed.

Comment: By the way, "Azure SQL Data Warehouse" is now "Azure Synapse Analytics". I fell back into the old terminology in answering your question, sorry :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ron, looks like there's a lot going on here, that I need to understand before being able to come to a conclusion whether to go with Azure SQL DB with Hyperscale OR Azure Synapse. From a pricing perspective and from a performance perspective. I do understand that Synapse is built for Petabytes of data and OLAP, but with Hyperscale Azure SQL DB also blurs the line by supporting "Hybrid (HTAP) and Analytical (data mart) workloads as well" with 100TB storage.